# Get Class from UITableViewCell identifier

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a big bunch of subclasses of UITableViewCell, all of these cells have a class method that returns the estimated height for the type of cell...

So what I want to do is be able to call that method just by knowing the cell identifier (I don't want to use a Switch mapping identifier with Class). I can't think of a way of doing it...

I know there is a NSClassFromString but I can't use that because my objects don't inherit from NSObject...

Any idea?

Comment: If they are subclasses of `UITableViewCell` then they inherit from `NSObject`. There is very few cases where you would have an object that doesn't inherit from `NSObject`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could **assign the class name as the cell identifier** and then do this:

```
Class cellClass = NSClassFromString(cellIdentifier);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` by calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` and cast it to your custom cell type. Then you can call any method you want.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(myIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
        // call class methods here
        return cell
    }
}
```